# Getting this error when requesting data from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I've been messing around with pulling data from API's but for some reason it gives me this error and I have no idea how to fix this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/Stats/DetailedStats?platform=2&personaId=376461834&displayName=TR_ISMAIL_TR&game=tunguska. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

So I generated this url from http://docs.trnbattlefield.apiary.io/#introduction/parameters/platform and I can see my in-game stats from Battlefield 1 on that site but when I copy paste the url to the web, it gives me a bad request.

So does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We will need more info, What are you using to call the API? HTTPRequest, AJAX?

Comment: As you're making a cross domain request you're being blocked by the Same Origin Policy as the receiving domain does not include CORS headers in the response. There is no workaround for this in JS. You will need to make the request server side instead

Comment: @CuriousDev Its a third party API

Answer (score 0):

If your using AJAX try setting the datatype to JSONP

```
$.ajax({
 url:"END POINT",
 dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
 success:function(json){       
     alert("Success");
 },
 error:function(){
     alert("Error");
 }      
});
```

Comment: This only works if the API sends a JSONP response (which is not directly interchangeable with JSON). It's not an automatic fix.

Comment: I'm assuming it does but your right it will not work if it doesn't.

Comment: Couldn't fix it for now I'll see what I can do. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot make a cross-domain AJAX request** if the server does not allow it (it is sometimes possible with "pre-flight" requests, explained in details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)).

**What you can do**, if you have control over your webserver, is to **make a reverse proxy** in order to access the remote data with a local URL.

Here is the way to do it with Apache (needs mod_proxy to be enabled):

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName www.yourserver.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass /bfapi/ https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/
    ProxyPassReverse /bfapi/ https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/
< /VirtualHost >
```

And if you use Nginx, place this in a server section of your config file:

```
location /bfapi/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/;
}
```

That way you can call the API with the following URL: https://yourserver.com/bfapi/Stats/DetailedStats?platform=2&personaId=376461834&displayName=TR_ISMAIL_TR&game=tunguska

Of course, you have to replace yourserver.com with your own domain.